# Using htaccess, how do you re-write for parameters over 8 characters or more only?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, unix, mod-rewrite

Using `.htaccess` file, I am trying to re-write the URL when the 'folder' is 8 or more characters long only. In other words:

`https://example.com/blog` - goes to the `/blog` folder

- but -

`https://example.com/12345678` - goes to `https://example.com/script.php?id=12345678`

Ideally, the answer would ensure that `https://example.com/12345678/` still works too (note the trailing slash `/`).

This is for a Linux server running on a shared hosting plan - think Hostgator, GoDaddy, etc.

This is so wrong, but:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [>8character]? "script.phpid=$1" ? "";
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.php.*$
RewriteRule ^([^\/]{8,})[^\/]*$ "/script.php?id=$1" [R,L]
```

- Uses RewriteCond as extra guard against a redirect loop

By default, the original query string is discarded when adding a new one, so if you want to preserve the original (so, `example.com/12345678?utm_campaign=foo` goes to `example.com/script.php?id=12345678&utm_campaign=foo`) use the [[QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)] flag, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.php.*$
RewriteRule ^([^\/]{8,})[^\/]*$ "/script.php?id=$1" [QSA,R,L]
```

If the ID is always just numbers, you could change the Regex to `^(\d{8,})[^\/]*$` to make it a little more foolproof.

Comment: You could avoid a rewrite loop by including a dot in the negated character class in the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (avoids the need for an additional condition). Also, why are you including `?` in the negated character class?

Comment: True, and my note about using `\d` would also address this, but OP was not clear if IDs are always integer based; I didn't want to assume that there are no IDs like "1234.11445", which would fail to redirect if I am negating periods. I negated `?` to avoid something like `/1234?abc=def`.

Comment: The query string is not part of the pattern, see `RewriteRule` "What is matched".

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for catching that! I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. Unfortunately, the solution above did not work. I tried commenting out all other Rewrite conditions and rules in my .htaccess and could not get it to work. When I use the answer above I get a 404 error for all entries, even just accessing the home page.

Comment: Make sure you are calling 'RewriteEngine On' before any RewriteRules - I've updated the code in my answer. Tested locally to make sure it is working.

Comment: Thanks again. Still having trouble. For the sample above here is what I get:
For both I get: This page is not working the page redirected you too many times. In the second one, it gets reflected in the URL with: `https://example.com/script.php?id=script.php&id=script.php&id=script.php&id=script.php&id=script.php&id=script.php&id=...script.php&id=script.php&id=script.php&id=VPDFMDitFT`

Comment: Sorry about that. The first one should have worked for you (and does work on my server) - not sure what the issue could be on your end. The second one I just edited again - you really need the RewriteCond in there both times. If you are still running into issues using the updated code, I would try clearing your cache and/or trying an incognito window.